# Python Curses update_panels() and Panel.move() issues

Tags: python, panel, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to learn how to use Python Curses (and hopefully build a simple game), but somehow I cannot get curses panels to work.

Specifically, when I try to update_panels(), my script (below) immediately exits directly back to the prompt.

```
import curses, curses.panel, time as t

def main(stdscr):
    # Initialize some colors and styles
    curses.start_color()
    curses.init_pair( 1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK )
    pl_style = curses.color_pair( 1 ) + curses.A_BOLD + curses.A_REVERSE

    # Create a Background window and panel
    bg_W = curses.newwin( 10, 100, 5, 5 )
    bg_W.box(); 
    bg_W.addstr( 1, 2, "BG Window" )
    bg_P = curses.panel.new_panel( bg_W )
    bg_W.refresh(); t.sleep( 2 )

    # Create a Player window and panel
    pl_W = curses.newwin( 1, 1, 10, 20 )
    pl_W.insch( '+', pl_style )
    pl_P = curses.panel.new_panel( pl_W )
    pl_W.refresh(); t.sleep( 2 )

    # Update panels
    curses.panel.update_panels()
    curses.doupdate()

    # # Move the Player panel and update panels
    # pl_P.move( 10, 30 )
    # curses.panel.update_panels()
    # curses.doupdate()
    # t.sleep( 2 )

    while True: 
        if pl_W.getch() == 27: break

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    curses.wrapper( main )
```

Alternatively, when I try to just move panels, my script (below), returns an error.

```
import curses, curses.panel, time as t

def main(stdscr):
    # Initialize some colors and styles
    curses.start_color()
    curses.init_pair( 1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK )
    pl_style = curses.color_pair( 1 ) + curses.A_BOLD + curses.A_REVERSE

    # Create a Background window and panel
    bg_W = curses.newwin( 10, 100, 5, 5 )
    bg_W.box(); 
    bg_W.addstr( 1, 2, "BG Window" )
    bg_P = curses.panel.new_panel( bg_W )
    bg_W.refresh(); t.sleep( 2 )

    # Create a Player window and panel
    pl_W = curses.newwin( 1, 1, 10, 20 )
    pl_W.insch( '+', pl_style )
    pl_P = curses.panel.new_panel( pl_W )
    pl_W.refresh(); t.sleep( 2 )

    # # Update panels
    # curses.panel.update_panels()
    # curses.doupdate()

    # Move the Player panel and update panels
    pl_P.move( 10, 30 )
    curses.panel.update_panels()
    curses.doupdate()
    t.sleep( 2 )

    while True: 
        if pl_W.getch() == 27: break

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    curses.wrapper( main )
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panl2.py", line 36, in <module>
    curses.wrapper( main )
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 105, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "panl2.py", line 27, in main
    pl_P.move( 10, 30 )
_curses_panel.error: move_panel() returned ERR
```

I've had a hell of a time trying to figure out what is wrong, but am getting absolutely nowhere, and would be very grateful for any guidance.

I'm using windows-curses (v2.1.0) with Python 3.8 (v3.8.1:1b293b6) in the standard Windows command prompt (v10.0.18362.449) on an x64 Windows 10 Pro (v10.0.18362) machine.

Answer (score 0):

ncurses' `move_panel` function returns the result from [`mvwin`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-mvwin), which is documented as follows:

> Calling **`mvwin`** moves the window so that the upper left-hand corner is at
>          position  (x,  y).   If  the  move would cause the window to be off the
>          screen, it is an error and the window is not moved.  Moving  subwindows
>          is allowed, but should be avoided.

In python, you'd have to use a try/except block to avoid simply exiting when there is an error-return from ncurses.

Using "windows-curses", the underlying library is probably PDCurses (which has no documentation aside from comments in the source-code).  However, its panel-support ultimately came from the same ([Warren Tucker](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/panel.3x.html#h2-AUTHOR)) implementation.  You can see the error-returns in the [source-code](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/618e0aaa31b4728eb4df78ec4de6c2b873908eda/pdcurses/panel.c#L452).

For what it's worth, the original panel library (author unknown) that one might have encountered in a vendor Unix machine (such as Solaris) did the same thing (see [source](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/lib/libeti/panel/common/move.c) on Illumos-gate), but the documentation provided could not have been useful when Tucker developed a clone (see ["documentation"](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/man/man3curses/panel_move.3curses)).